# C# ASP.NET MVC Access SMTP settings from config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I seem to be stuck.  I have an asp.net mvc 4 app and I want to send email from a service class.  The service class is in a C# library project separate from the mvc project in the solution.  I want to set the email configuration in a separate file that is called from a config file.  Should the following go in the web.config in the mvc project or create an app.config file in the service project?

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
       <smtp configSource="MailSettings.config" />
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Then I have this in a separate file called MailSettings.config:

```
<smtp from="abc@email.com">
   <network host="smtp.server.com" port="587" userName="abc@email.com" password="password" enableSsl="true" />
</smtp>
```

I have tried creating an app.config file with just the system.net stuff for the service project, but the mail settings are always null when I try:

```
MailSettingsSectionGroup settings = (MailSettingsSectionGroup)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings");
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(settings.Smtp.Network.Host); //get null exception for settings.Smtp.Network.Host)
```

Also, I've tried including the mail settings in the app.config file to rule out having the MailSettings.config file being the issue and that still generates a null pointer.

I tried an example for accessing it from the web.config file like so:

```
Configuration configurationFile = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
MailSettingsSectionGroup mailSettings = configurationFile.GetSectionGroup("system.net/mailSettings") as MailSettingsSectionGroup;
```

In the service class though the `WebConfigurationManager` is out of context and so is the `Request.ApplicationPath`.  So if I do have to get it from the web.config file, would I have to pass the http request object to the service class?  That seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use:

```
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();
```

This constructor will pick the configuration directly.

As the MSDN documentation for the [parameterless constructor of `SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1c4h6e2.aspx) says:

> This constructor initializes the Host, Credentials, and Port properties for the new SmtpClient by using the settings in the application or machine configuration files. For more information, see [`<mailSettings>` Element (Network Settings)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx).